# Accessing a Sorted List by Key in VB.NET, Is there any difference between mySortedList(Key) and mySortedList.Item(Key)?

Tags: vb.net

Noticing that SortedList can be accessed either by Key or Index, I tested a little bit to be sure I knew what was happening with mySortedList(1), which I couldn't find a clear definition for in the MS documentation. My initial concern was, could this approach be calling the value by index and I just wasn't aware, if the keys were integers? But what I walked away with was mostly curiosity about this approach vs. mySortedList.Item(1), which *was* clearly defined in the documentation.
Documentation I am referring to is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist?view=netframework-4.7.2
Testing I did was in a Visual Studio VB.Net Console App using .Net Framework 4.7.2

```
Dim mySortedList As New SortedList(Of Integer, String)
mySortedList.Add(3, "0 index, 3 key") '<--Add adds by (key, value)
mySortedList.Add(2, "1 index, 2 key")
mySortedList.Add(1, "2 index, 1 key")

Debug.WriteLine(mySortedList(1)) '<-- this is by key (gets or sets), but I haven't seen it documented
Debug.WriteLine(mySortedList.Item(1)) '<-- this is by key ("gets or sets") 
Debug.WriteLine(mySortedList.ElementAt(1)) '<--This is by index (retrieves only)

'checking setting values using these methods
mySortedList(1) = "set by key 1"
mySortedList.Item(2) = "set by key 2"
'mySortedList.ElementAt(2) = "set by Index 2" '<--"Expression is a value and cannot be used as the target of an assignment"

Debug.WriteLine(mySortedList(1))
Debug.WriteLine(mySortedList(2))
```

Output:

```
2 index, 1 key
2 index, 1 key
[2, 1 index, 2 key]
set by key 1
set by key 2
```

Is there any difference between mySortedList(Key) and mySortedList.Item(Key)?
is there any documentation for the mySortedList(Key) approach? Is there a reason I didn't find it documented (maybe it's deprecated or something like that?) or a reason not to use it? Is this behavior just inherited from a parent class maybe?

Comment: First lines in the remarks section of the [docs for the Item property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist.item?view=netframework-4.7.2) say: _You can use the Item[] property to access a specific element in a collection by specifying the following syntax: myCollection[key]._ They are using the C# syntax even in the VB.NET page but it should be clear enough

Comment: No difference, it is the [default property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-declare-and-call-a-default-property)

Comment: Thanks Steve, that looks like just the explanation I was looking for, the documentation for the item property clearly states it can be accessed in this way. 
Also thank you Hans, I wasn't aware of "default property" functionality before now, but I can see that Item(key as TKey) is the default property for Class SortedList(of Tkey, TValue) when I check it's class definition, and the documentation you linked explains the "why" of how calling mySortedList(Key) returns mySortedList.Item(Key)

Comment: `Item` is the name that the **indexer** gets in VB (which is related to default properties but might not be exactly the same thing).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netframework-4.7.2  might be what you are looking for.